# Application installed on Play Store but not launching Android

Tags: android

Application being published on Play Store but cannot launch it.

My app is being downloaded on Play Store but cannot view it on the screen or see the logo anywhere. After installing, there is no 'Open" option either

The MainActivity has launch intent so i do not know what is the issue. 
Here is my Manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.blommaritime.app1">

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_pros"
        android:label="BLOM Maritime"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo_pros"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.contact_us" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.Projects"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.Water_slide"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.Projects" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.BW_offshore"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.Projects" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.Grand_Princess"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.Projects" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.ECGS_services"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.Projects" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.Hull_Mesh"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.Projects" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.About_us"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.Services_Home"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.Clients" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.ECGS"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.Services_Home" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.NUbes"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.Services_Home" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.Naval_Architecture"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.Services_Home" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.Laser_scanning"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.Services_Home" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.engineering"
            android:parentActivityName="com.blommaritime.app1.Services_Home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.blommaritime.app1.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=" android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>!
```

[this is what it looks like when the app is searched for in the phone]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvazH.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the screenshots ?

Comment: Do you see the app logo when you install/launch the app from Android Studio?

Comment: No I can’t see the app logo either